# Restricting Users to View Only the Items They Have Uploaded?

Tags: php

I'm kinda struggling on how to show the users only their Uploads. I have a login system and logged in user can upload images, but when showing the images the user sees all the images uploaded by all users instead of only theirs.  I have two databases one for the login one for the upload.

I had asked this before but I couldn't get it work(I was told to use Foreign Key)..I also did a Google search and found out [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded/4412#4412/) but couldn't get it...does anyone have any Idea? I would be surprised if you show me kind of example. Thanks. I'm using php to upload and show images

This is what I have in database(I switched to one database)

**Images**

```
id | photo | Author|
```

**Users**

```
id | username | Password|...
```

Comment: " I would be surprised if you show me kind of example. " -- so would I. You haven't specifed a language.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have two databases or two tables in one database?

If the latter, add a column into your upload table called "userid", where userid is same as the primary key of the login. When showing the images, show the only images where

SELECT * FROM images WHERE userid = login.userid

Comment: @Haymi are you sure? Normally there's not a single reason for that.

Comment: I'm sure I have two databases, I can make it one if that is an issue.

Comment: @Haymi well, it could be a major complication, trying to get two databases to cooperate.

Comment: @Haymi there's a difference between two **tables** and two **databases**, which one do you have? If the latter, what on Earth for?

Comment: @JanDvorak One to many relationships for a foreign key; and would you really want the uploaded files contained in a table the user will login with?

Comment: @hd1 I can understand that. I'm using MySQL database. if having two databases is an issue, I can use one database and create tables in it.

Comment: It seems like an unnecessary complication of using two databases. Switch two one database and create multiple tables, as the Jan and DAryl suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do. You could change around your file uploader to insert information into a database, such as the location of the file, ownership, views/clicks etc...

**Update** *Start*

Modify your tables to the following:

*Images*

> id | OwnerID | photo | Author|

Setup a one to many relationship from the users table (preferably the ID) to the OwnerID in your Images table... Then, on your insert, input `$UserID` where OwnerID is;

$UserID should be defined by the username (unique..) then when selecting from your images, ensure you select all files listed as: `Images.UserID = $UserID`

*End*

This is just an example.

when uploading, insert a row into the uploads table, identifying the bits you want.

Then when it comes to viewing,

only select/list your items within a loop, which are listed by either the USERID (identified in ID on user table) or the username, in the upload table.

Build your code structure around this basis

Comment: Could you post your schema layout for these two specific databases; It would assist further. Makesure you update your question

Comment: I wish I could get this working...whatever I try It just doesn't work...the $UserID part is really confusing me..when you say setup a one to many r/ship from users table, is that the same as specifying a Foreign Key? Isn't there any way I could use the  $_GET Variable to get the user name and insert it to the Images table along with the photo? Your example seems right but I don't see my self getting it..